# Java Regex Issue with Quantifiers

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the following code using Java 7 to validate the format of a file:

```
private boolean validateFile(String image) {    
    // Get width and height on image
    ...
    ...
    //Multiply by three, once for each R,G, and B value for the pixel
    int entriesRequired = width * height * 3;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("w=\\d+\\s+h=\\d+\\s+OK\\s+[\\d+\\s+]{" + entriesRequired + "}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(image);

    return matcher.matches();
}
```

The file, which I've read into a String and is being held by the `image` variable, appears as so:

```
"w=1\nh=2\nOK\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n"
```

I'm expecting `validateFile(String image)` to return True, but it's been returning false. Any regex experts out there who can help me out?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: @BackSlash If you mean the metacharacter `\n` (newline), then you're wrong. `\s` is `[ \r\n\v\t\f]`.

Comment: don't you have to parenthesis what your repeating ?   (.....){ + entriesRequired + }

Comment: What is your value for entriesRequired? I think you have it calculated wrong. You also have to calculate for the new lines, it works with 12 in your case.

Comment: Please check the Java 7 API (java.util.regex.Pattern under "Predefined character class). Unless I'm interpreting it wrong, \s includes all whitespace, including \n (newline)

Comment: The value for entriesRequired in this case is 6

Comment: Try 12, see my comment edit above. You need to match the newlines too. See here: http://rubular.com/r/thI34Fq6if

Comment: @morja Thank you for your help. That worked :) However, I don't understand why it did. If I was including decimal characters and whiteline characters in the block [\\d+\\s+]{6} wouldn't I be looking for something like 10\n or 8\n 6 times instead of 12?

Comment: The character class `[]` does not care about order, it is a set. If you have two characters each match of those two is counted. If you want to handle it as a tuple of characters see the answer from BackSlash and use groups `()` or `(?:)` brackets for non capturing groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is wrong.

```
"w=\\d+\\s+h=\\d+\\s+OK\\s+[\\d+\\s+]{" + entriesRequired + "}"
```

`[\\d+\\s+]{n}` Means "String of length `n` created using any of `\d`, `\s`, `+`."

What you want is `\d+\s+` repeated n times, so change the brackets to parenthesis:

```
"w=\\d+\\s+h=\\d+\\s+OK\\s+(\\d+\\s+){" + entriesRequired + "}"
```

It works for me

---

Side note: in that particular case you don't need `Pattern` and `Matcher`, you can just use

```
image.matches("w=\\d+\\s+h=\\d+\\s+OK\\s+(\\d+\\s+){" + entriesRequired + "}");
```

Since your regex validates the entire string

Comment: Thanks for the help and the image.matches(regex) recommendation. That'll cut down on my code.